# Internet explorer9 is opening my website in quirks mode automatically? How to fix it?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, doctype

Here I am using html 5 doctype but IE9 rendering it into quirks mode automatically. I used a meta tag to fix it but it is not working.

Here is the my head section code and URl please fix it.

URL: http://www.dual-amps.com/SeeHearDemo3/hukf7vh4i/default.aspx

if full code is required please let me know..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Dual Amplifiers</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://revenewonline.net/web/dual/dual_amplifier/LP/css/style1.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://revenewonline.net/web/dual/dual_amplifier/LP/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://revenewonline.net/web/dual/dual_amplifier/LP/js/tabcontent.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://revenewonline.net/web/dual/dual_amplifier/LP/css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" />
<script src="https://revenewonline.net/web/dual/dual_amplifier/LP/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://revenewonline.net/web/dual/dual_amplifier/LP/js/common1.js"></script>
<link href="https://revenewonline.net/web/dual/dual_amplifier/LP/images/favicon.ico" rel="Shortcut Icon" />
<meta name="Keywords" content="Powerful Amps for Powerful Sound" />
<meta name="Description" content="Powerful Amps for Powerful Sound" />
</head>
```

Comment: remove this: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Use below line in <head>

> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >